# How to play a List of video carousel in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to play a list of video in in a carousel. I tried to combine package like swiper and other carousel package and with video player.
I pass the URL to custom video Player class and and pass the URL according to the onIndexChanged function, But sometimes the 2nd video get initialize then the first.

Comment: Can you add your code?

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be instead of using a custom carousel package, try using PageView.builder and then pass the indexedPage.